# How to use img.shape() in javascript

Tags: javascript, python, html, css

import cv2

## read image

`img = cv2.imread('/home/img/python.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)`

## get dimensions of image

`dimensions = img.shape`

## height, width, number of channels in image

```
height = img.shape[0]
width = img.shape[1]
channels = img.shape[2]

 
print('Image Dimension    : ',dimensions)
print('Image Height       : ',height)
print('Image Width        : ',width)
print('Number of Channels : ',channels)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You need to provide more details. JavaScript is just a language, and does not tell anyone where it runs, server side or client side. Which library is this?

Answer (score 0):

for the amount of channels you need to do

```py
channels = image.shape[-1] if image.ndim == 3 else 1
```

This is because the amount of channels will not be shown if it is grayscale. And that is why image.ndim is checked.

To get width and height just do what you already did in your example

And for dimensions you could do:

```py
dimensions = f"{width}x{height}"
```

if you want it to return in a string. Otherwise, if you want it to return as a tuple it will just be the first 2 objects in img.shape.